# Use Night resources on Light theme

Tags: android, android-resources, android-theme, material-components-android

I'm using the Material Component's dark theme style, everything is working fine but now I need to show a particular view with a different theme to obtain more contrast.
I've defined my main theme in `values/themes.xml` like that:

```xml
<style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/color_primary_variant</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/color_on_primary</item>
    ...
</style>
```

and two different colors resources in `values/colors.xml` and `values-night/colors.xml`.

What I would like to do is to find a way to retrieve the light theme colors when the dark theme is used (and vice-versa) or to apply the opposite theme to a single view.

The only solution I found was to simply define two variants (normal and "reversed") for each color in both `colors.xml` files, but since there are many colors defined I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid having to define multiple light/dark values variant for each color, I defined a custom style that refers to the opposite theme variant, e.g. in `values/styles.xml` I defined:

```xml
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.Reverse" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark"/>
```

and in `values-night/styles.xml`:

```xml
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.Reverse" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light"/>
```

Then in the root of layout where I want to use the "reversed" theme:

```xml
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.Reverse">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```